# Type org.pitest.maven.PitMojo not present

Tags: java, maven, java-7, mutation-testing, pitest

I am using java 1.7, maven 3.6.3, I have added the PIT plugin to do some mutation testing. However, getting the below issue. AFAIK, PIT will work for java 5 or above, but here I am getting

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/pitest/maven/PitMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

Changing the PIT version is still downloading :pitest-maven:1.6.7, Any hints or help is highly appreciated. I also attached the error log below:

### POM File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>branch_cov_testcase</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <compilerArgs>
                            <arg>-g:source,lines,vars</arg>
                        </compilerArgs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.0.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <generateHistorical>true</generateHistorical>
                        <jdk>1.7</jdk>                
                        <includesTestSourceRoots>false</includesTestSourceRoots>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/code_cov_tool/*.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openclover</groupId>
                <artifactId>clover-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
                <version>LATEST</version>
                <configuration>
                    <targetClasses>
                        <param>test_cov.*</param>
                    </targetClasses>
                    <targetTests>
                        <param>test_cov.*</param>
                    </targetTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </reporting>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.pitest/pitest-maven -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
            <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- ==================================================================== -->
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.21.0</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.compilerVersion>1.7</maven.compiler.compilerVersion>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.debug>true</maven.compiler.debug>
        <maven.compiler.debuglevel>lines,source</maven.compiler.debuglevel>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Error Log:

```
[INFO] --- pitest-maven:1.6.7:mutationCoverage (default-cli) @ branch_cov_testcase ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.pitest.maven.PitMojo
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.pitest.maven.PitMojo not present
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass (URLClassSpace.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.NamedClass.load (NamedClass.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/pitest/maven/PitMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass (ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass (SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass (URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100 (URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf (ClassRealm.java:425)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass (URLClassSpace.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.NamedClass.load (NamedClass.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why using JDK 7?

Comment: Are you compiling and running the code with the same JDK? Looks like you compiled the code with a higher JDK.

Comment: I am using 1.7 for some reason, I am using another tool that only works with Java 6 or 7, I am using Java 7 for compiling and running. mvn clean compile test works perfectly but when I am using PIT, it's giving errors.

Comment: This is what I am getting : Failed to execute goal org.pitest:pitest-maven:1.6.7:mutationCoverage (default-cli) on project branch_cov_testcase: Execution default-cli of goal org.pitest:pitest-maven:1.6.7:mutationCoverage failed: Unable to load the mojo 'mutationCoverage' in the plugin 'org.pitest:pitest-maven:1.6.7' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: org/pitest/maven/PitMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Comment: Well, this kind of error is probably because of different JDKs used for compiling and executing the code.

Comment: I understand, but thats not happening here, I have checked several times, also the target classes are java 7, and the mnv Java home is the same as Java 7.

Comment: Pitest requires a minimum of Java 8 to run.

Comment: yeah, I got it worked with Java 8, In the PIT document haven't seen any such requirement though

Comment: @henry but FAQ says that Java 5+ is required. If that's not true, can this be updated? https://pitest.org/faq/ in question: "What are the requirements for running PIT?"

Comment: @dgebert that page hasn't been touched for a few years, updated now.